# Deploying via SSH with Vlad

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, vlad-deployer

I have a private Github repo and am trying to set-up Vlad to deploy it to my server. I am getting `Host key verification failed` when I `rake vlad:update` - as I haven't defined any shh keys or entered any passwords. I'm not really sure where to start. What's the easiest and most secure way to do this?

My current `deploy.rb` is:

```
set :application, "<project>"
set :domain, "ubuntu@<ip>"
set :deploy_to, "/srv/http/<project>.com"
set :repository, 'git@github.com:<user>/<project>.git'
```

Comment: Host key verification errors usually mean that the host key (not ssh key) has changed, perhaps the server you are ssh'ing to has changed but you are using the same name?  Try to ssh manually, and if it gives you an error you can remove the key with ssh-keygen -R <hostname> and re-do.

Comment: Yes if I `ssh git@github.com:<user>/<project>.git` then I get the same error - but I can still `git push` perfectly okay?

Comment: I would probably remove the key with ssh-keygen -R, and then do it.  Verify that the host is correct, though.  The host key is a security measure so that people can't replace servers without you knowing about it.  But you should be able to push fine.  I probably should have put this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have two machines, development and server. I think you need a key pair between server and github such that the server can access github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's what I did to sort this out:

- Create a public / private key pair
- Add the private key to the server using puppet
- Add a known host file to the server using puppet
- Add the public key as a deploy hook in github repo settings